# Missing transaction

Tags: blockchain, tokens, defi, withdrawal

MISSING TRANSACTION

I have no idea what went wrong here but I had tried to send two tokens to my coinbase wallet from my crypto. Com defi wallet . And it never arrived . I also messed up and sent a token called LADY to the same address by mistake . 0xc331b896682C07C96BC2EC3f78873B143E032320
Any suggestions. I sure would like to have these back.